# image path and $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']

Tags: php, wordpress

I've some images in my wordpress plugin folder.Folder structure is `xx->wp-content->plugins->plugname->images->..` So,when i try to call only "/images/myimage.png/"; It didn't work. but when i call `xx/wp-contents/plugins/plugname/images/myimage.png'` Then it works.Currently I'm trying this on local host.When another person will try this his domain name will be different!!Should i use `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` instead of `xx` Give any solution or ideas for solving this problem.

Thanks is advance

Answer (score 3):

You can use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."your_project_folder_name/wp-contents/.........."` like this.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set your link relative to the document root. This means that you need to call "/wp-content/plugins/plugname/images/myimage.png". You just need to leave off "xx".

/images/myimage.png is the same as calling http://mysite.com/images/myimage.png", which isn't right, and because a widget is displayed within another page, any relative link needs to be set with respect to the page that includes the widget.